# Using dot method in Object type array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

Using dot method in Object type array in Java:

```java
class patient {
  int id;
  public String name;
  String pNum;

  patient() {
    id=0;
    name=null;
    pNum=null;
  }

  patient(int i, String n, String p) {
    id =i;
    name=n;
    pNum=p;
  }

  String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public String toString() {
    String str="ID           : "+id+"\n"+"Name         : "+name+"\n"+"Phone Number :"+pNum+"\n";
    return str;
  }
}
```

When I tried to use it with conventional queue class by `q` static object I couldn't do `so[i].getName();` function or `so[i].name;` and it `gives cannot find symbol` error.

like this code below:

```java
 static void ShowAllPatient() {
    Object [] so=q.toArray();

    String str=so[0].getName();
    for(int i=0; i<ob.length; i++) {
      System.out.println(so[i].name);
    }
  }
```

Comment: `so` is of type `Object[]`, so its elements are of type `Object`. `Object` doesn't have a `getName()` method. Not sure what you were expecting.

Comment: I wanted to get the String name from the object array 'so' where the value was stored before by other method.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `so` is of type `Object[]`, the `Object` doesn't have `getName` method. The Collection `q` should define a type of the element, then use

```
patient[] so=q.toArray(new patient[q.size()]);
```

Comment: `<T> T[] toArray(T[] a)` for `List`.

Comment: But toArray() method don't take any argument or perameter.